# ASP.NET caching w/file dependency: static var vs. AspNet cache vs. memcached

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, memcached

**TL;DR: Which is likely faster: accessing static local variable, accessing variable stored in HttpRuntime.Cache, or accessing variable stored in memcached?**

At work, we get about 200,000 page views/day. On our homepage, we display a promotion. This promotion is different for different users, based on their country of origin and language.

All the different promotions are defined in an XML file on each web server. We have 12 web servers all serving the same site with the same XML file. There are about 50 different promotion combinations based on country/language. We imagine we'll never have more than 200 or so (if ever) promotions (combinations) total.

The XML file may be changed at any time, out of release cycle. When it's changed, the new definitions of promotions should immediately change on the live site. Implementing the functionality for this requirement is the responsibility of another developer and I.

Originally, I wrote the code so that the contents of the XML file were parsed and then stored in a static member of a class. A `FileSystemWatcher` monitored changes to the file, and whenever the file was changed, the XML would be reloaded/reparsed and the static member would be updated with the new contents. Seemed like a solid, simple solution to keeping the in-memory dictionary of promotions current with the XML file. (Each server doing this indepedently with its local copy of the XML file; all XML files are the same and change at the same time.)

The other developer I was working holds a Sr. position and decided that this was no good. Instead, we should store all the promotions in each server's `HttpContext.Current.Cache` with a `CacheDependency` file dependency that automatically monitored file changes, expunging the cached promotions when the file changed. While I liked that we no longer had to use a `FileSystemWatcher`, I worried a little that grabbing the promotions from the volitile cache instead of a static class member would be less performant.

(Care to comment on this concern? I already gave up trying to advocate not switching to HttpRuntime.Cache.)

Later, after we began using `HttpRuntime.Cache`, we adopted memcached with Enyim as our .NET interface for other business problems (e.g. search results). When we did that, this Sr. Developer decided we should be using memcached instead of the `HttpRuntime` (`HttpContext`) `Cache` for storing promotions. Higher-ups said "yeah, sounds good", and gave him a dedicated server with memcached just for these promotions. Now he's currently implementing the changes to use memcached instead.

I'm skeptical that this is a good decision. Instead of staying in-process and grabbing this promotion data from the `HttpRuntime.Cache`, we're now opening a socket to a network memcached server and transmitting its value to our web server.

This has to be less performant, right? Even if the cache is memcached. (I haven't had the chance to compile any performance metrics yet.)

On top of that, he's going to have to engineer his own file dependency solution over memcached since it doesn't provide such a facility.

Wouldn't my original design be best? Does this strike you as overengineering? Is `HttpRuntime.Cache` caching or memcached caching even necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing exactly how much data you are talking about (assuming it's not a lot), I tend to somewhat agree with you; raw-speed wise, a static member should be the 'fastest', then `Cache`. That doesn't necessarily mean it's the best option, of course. Scalability is not always about speed. In fact, the things we do for scalability often negatively (marginally) affect the speed of an application.

More specifically; I do tend to start with the Cache object myself, unless a bit of 'static' data is pretty darn small and is pretty much guaranteed to be needed constantly (in which case I go for static members. Don't forget thread synch too, of course!)

With a modest amount of data that won't change often at all, and can easily be modified when you need to, by altering the files as you note, the `Cache` object is probably a good solution. `memcached` may be overkill, and overly complex... but it should work, too.

I think the major possible 'negative' to the memcached solution is the single-point-of-failure issue; Using the local server's `Cache` keeps each server isolated.

It sounds like there may not really be any choice in your case, politically speaking. But I think your reasoning isn't necessarily all that bad, given what you've shared here.

Answer (score 3):

Very much agree with Andrew here. Few additions/deviations:

1. For small amount of rarely changing data, static fields would offer best performance. When your caching happens at no UI layer, it avoids taking dependency on System.Web assembly (of course, you can achieve this by other means as well as). However, in general, ASP.NET Cache would also be a good bet (especially when data is large, the cached data can expire if there is memory pressure etc.)
2. From both speed & scalability, output caching (including browser & down level caching) would be the best option and you should evaluate it. Even if data is changing frequently, output caching for 30-60 seconds can give significant performance boost for very large number of requests. If needed, you can do partial caching (user controls) and/or substitutions. Of course, this needs to be done with combination with data caching.